# Automate Removing "Flip To Boot" on Lenovo 82H8

Tags: registry, regedit

**Background:** I have a set of Lenovo 82H8 laptops that have a pre-enabled feature called "Flip to Boot". Essentially this feature automatically turns on the computer when the lid is opened.

**Problem:** The problem is that the "Flip to Boot" mechanism causes the device to power on in transit to its destination, causing my users to be given a laptop with a dead battery.

I have a few ways to manually disable this, but it adds an extra few minutes to my prep process.
Is there a method I have been unable to find that can disable this feature via commands?

---

**What I have tried:** I can turn the feature off via the Power settings in Lenovo Vantage (a program that comes with these devices), or by disabling the setting in BIOS, or I can change the setting in "control.exe powercfg.cpl,,3". But to do this I need to run the following command to enable the Flip To Boot setting in the powercfg menu:

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347\99ff10e7-23b1-4c07-a9d1-5c3206d741b4 /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /reg:32
```

This command is helpful, but it's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to fully automate this process and push it out to every device of the same make/model on my domain.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issues. shutdown your system and turn on again, at that time  click f2 button . In BIOS go to configuration. disable the flip to boot and go to exit and click exit and apply. After that the problem issues are fixed.